# Batch Rename specific digit of a filename

Tags: bash, file-rename, batch-rename

I have lots of files to be renamed. Below are the examples:

```
 D801040001 ---> D801041401   /
 D801040002 ---> D801041402   /
 O010900001 ---> O010914001   /
 O010900002 ---> O010914002
```

For D8 files, I just want to change the 7th and 8th digit to '14'.
For O0 files, 6th and 7th digit to '14' also.

My problem is, I don't know how to rename the files using script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

for case 1:

```
rename 's/^(D8.{4})..(.*)$/${1}14${2}/' D8*
```

for case 2:

```
rename 's/^(O0.{3})..(.*)$/${1}14${2}/' O0*
```

Comment: Sir, can you ellaborate those cases?

Comment: I tried it using cmd, but it says "The syntax of the command is incorrect".

Comment: it shows 'which' is not recognized as an internal o external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `bash`:

**Case1:**

```
for file in D*; do mv "$file" "${file/#D8010400/D8010414}"; done
```

**Case2:**

```
for file in O*; do mv "$file" "${file/#O010900/O010914}"; done
```

**Explanation:**

```
${string/#substring/replacement}
```

If `$substring` matches front end of `$string`, substitute `$replacement` for `$substring`.

```
${string/%substring/replacement}
```

If `$substring` matches back end of `$string`, substitute `$replacement` for `$substring`.